# How to increase NavigatorIOS transition speed?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to use NavigatorIOS (I know it's not well supported but it's a small project and I want something that looks like the iOS Navigation Bar). However, the transition speed between routes is brutally slow. It takes over 2 seconds to slide from one screen to another and during that time I can't interact with either screen. Is there any way to increase the transition time. Here's the entirety of my index.ios.js if that helps:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

var Awesome = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={{flex: 1}}
        initialRoute={{
          component: AwesomeTest,
          title: 'Awesome',
        }} />
    );
  }
});

var AwesomeTest = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._next}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  },

  _next: function() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: AwesomeNext,
      title: 'AwesomeTest',
    });
  }
});

var AwesomeNext = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Text>It works</Text>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 200,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Awesome', () => Awesome);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This confused me once too. Try `Command` + `T` to shut off a feature of xcode that allows you to slow down animations for precision and debug purposes

Comment: Command+T is the Xcode command for "New Tab".  Please explain what this does??

Answer (score 0):

Command + T works fine (need to be performed on the simulator, not on Xcode)